# How to print response body to stdout/stderr on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I would like to print out response body generated by my app to stdout/stderr for debugging purposes. The traffic is server-server so I cannot use client tools to get hold of http traffic.

There is a mention of `puts @response.body` in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html, however in my app controller `@response` is undefined. Is there a way for me to print response body to logs in my rails app, and if so, how?

---

Based on the answer given, did it like this:

```
after_filter :print_response_body, :only => [:index]

def print_response_body 
  $stderr.puts response.body
end
```

Comment: Nice, they actually changed the api documentation as well after this was asked and answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller, try

```
after_filter do
  puts response.body
end
```